# Using jq to parse invalid JSON?

Tags: linux, terminal, json, jq

Can jq parse invalid JSON such as this?:

```
[2023.06.07-21.58.47] StatManagerLog: {
    "RoundState":
    {
        "State": "Starting",
        "Timestamp": "2023.06.07-21.58.47"
    }
}
[2023.06.07-21.58.47] StatManagerLog: {
    "RoundState":
    {
        "State": "StandBy",
        "Timestamp": "2023.06.07-21.58.47"
    }
}
```

Ideally each StatManagerLog object would be read by jq.

Cannot seem to find out how jq can do this. I've tried using `-R` but then I lose the ability to do any of jq's commands. Is this possible or do I need to pre-process the file first to make it valid JSON?

Comment: `-r` affects the output only, did you mean you tried `-R`?

Comment: (Edited) Yes, I tried  `-R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with `jq` in particular, nevertheless, I hope this answer will be useful.

Writing a parser (which parses a file according to a fixed grammar) is generally a complicated and painful task.

Writing a parser that can correct mistakes is on a whole another level. I can't even imagine how complex it could be!

Think about the different ways the input you've shown could be "corrected".

Maybe that `[2023.06.07-21.58.47]` was meant to have `,` instead of `.` and `-`, that is, the array of six items `[2023,06,07,21,58,47]`... but then what to do with the rest?

Maybe the whole `[2023.06.07-21.58.47] StatManagerLog:` is meant to be dropped? Then the file is not a single JSON but a couple of JSON files concatenated; something that `jq` seems to be able to cope with.

Maybe it's meant to be `"[2023.06.07-21.58.47] StatManagerLog":`, i.e. the double quotes are missing around the key, and a big outer `{` `}` pair encapsulating the entire file is missing too.

I'm sure there are also a few other possibilities where fixes of about this size could make the file a valid JSON. The parser would have no idea which one to choose.

This is similar to spoken languages. Think of how many times you don't clearly hear the entire sentence and ask back because your brain couldn't automatically correct the unheard part... possibly because you can imagine more than 1 way of correcting the sentence and they would result in different meaning.

Long story short: Only you know how exactly the data needs to be fixed, what the original intent was; the parser has no chance of figuring it out. Fix it using some text processing tools (`sed`, `awk`, `cut`, etc.) before feeding it to `jq`. Or fix whoever emits this data to emit proper JSON.

Comment: Just two quick and dirty example: `cat jqprb |sed "s/\(\[.*\].*\):.*{/{\"\1\": {/"|sed "s/^}/}}/"|jq .` or `cat jqprb |sed "s/\[.*\].*/{/"|jq .`

Answer (score 2):

Pre-processing the file by simply replacing each line that starts with `[` with a `{` would make it valid JSON, or at least concatenation of valid JSONs which `jq` is also able to handle:

```bash
$ sed 's/^\[.*/{/' file | jq -c .
{"RoundState":{"State":"Starting","Timestamp":"2023.06.07-21.58.47"}}
{"RoundState":{"State":"StandBy","Timestamp":"2023.06.07-21.58.47"}}
```

I assume you don't need the removed information as it comprises data already included in the output (the timestamp) and static strings (`StatManagerLog`).

You may then select the entries that you need, e.g., by state or timestamp:

```bash
$ sed 's/^\[.*/{/' file | jq -c --arg q 2023.06.07-21.58.47 'select(.RoundState.Timestamp == $q)'
{"RoundState":{"State":"Starting","Timestamp":"2023.06.07-21.58.47"}}
{"RoundState":{"State":"StandBy","Timestamp":"2023.06.07-21.58.47"}}
$ sed 's/^\[.*/{/' file | jq -c --arg q StandBy 'select(.RoundState.State == $q)'
{"RoundState":{"State":"StandBy","Timestamp":"2023.06.07-21.58.47"}}
```

... or by some more involved selection of any aggregate that you need.